# nath and biblatex incompatibility

Tags: biblatex, incompatibility, nath

I try to use nath and couldn't get it to work within my document. So I started to track down the error with a minimal and adding all packages that I use after and after. I saw that I can load every package without errors (if I load nath at the very end) except the biblatex package. I get lots of errors when I load the biblatex package. Is there a workaround?

Here's the minimal I compile:

```
\documentclass[
  paper=A4,
  pagesize,
  fontsize=10pt,
  draft=false
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{nath}
\usepackage[
    style=numeric-comp,
    bibstyle=numeric,
    sorting=none,
    url=false
]{biblatex}
% \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p)^{\displayed{\frac 1p}}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: So you're saying there is no way of using both `nath` an `biblatex`?

Comment: The `nath` package also looks rather old. Sad that it's development is frozen. It has some features that makes math much more straightforward. On the other hand, biblatex is must... There is no other package which is more compatible with everything else (biblatex is not the only package which causes problems) that has some of the nice features `nath` offers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my surprise (`nath` does a lot of low level catcode changes), swapping the load order of `nath` and `biblatex` works.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[
  paper=A4,
  pagesize,
  fontsize=10pt,
  draft=false
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,
    bibstyle=numeric,
    sorting=none,
    url=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{nath}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p)^{\displayed{\frac 1p}}
\end{equation}
\cite{test}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with `ref.bib` containing

```
@Article{test,
  author =   {Author, A. N.},
  title =    {Title},
  journal =  {Journal},
  year =     2010
}
```

## File versions

The following versions of files were used in this example:

```
 *File List*
scrartcl.cls    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script document class (article)
scrkbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2012/06/15 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2012/04/04 v3.10b KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize10pt.clo    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script font size class option (10pt)
typearea.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (type area)
biblatex.sty    2013/01/10 v2.5 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2013/01/10 v2.5 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)

etoolbox.sty    2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  logreq.sty    2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
  logreq.def    2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
  ifthen.sty    2001/05/26 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
     url.sty    2006/04/12  ver 3.3  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  blx-dm.def
numeric-comp.dbx
biblatex-dm.cfg
blx-compat.def    2013/01/10 v2.5 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.def    
standard.bbx    2013/01/10 v2.5 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
 numeric.bbx    2013/01/10 v2.5 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
numeric-comp.cbx    2013/01/10 v2.5 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex.cfg    
    nath.sty    
 english.lbx    2013/01/10 v2.5 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
       q.bbl
 ***********
```

Comment: And I am surprised too, because it does not work for me... I tried that myself and the only thing I can get `nath` to work is to not use `biblatex`.

Comment: Well I have to correct myself a little. I compiles with about 7 errors but the output some how looks like it is using `nath` and the references seem to be correct as well. I'll post the errors later and maybe someone can tell me if it is severe.

Comment: The `biblatex` I am using is pretty new - may be updating would help.