# Incompatibilities with and alternatives to nath

Tags: math-mode, incompatibility, automation, nath

I just discovered the existence of `nath` to auto-size mathematical expressions. But I also read that it has many incompatibilities and it also doesn't seem to be maintained anymore (last update was 2003). I found so far *[Are nath and xcolor incompatible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84563/are-nath-and-xcolor-incompatible)* and *[nath and biblatex incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100809/nath-and-biblatex-incompatibility)*. I use both (`xcolor` implicitly and `biblatex` explicitly) in my real world document. But `nath` seems to interfere with `tikz` and/or `pgfplots`, too, as I get errors from them when loading `nath` in my real world document.

As it would be very hard to narrow down all the points where nath and my other packages/code interfere to create a MWE, I'll ask some general questions with the hope to get a summary of the state, applicability and usefulness of `nath` nowadays in modern, complex documents:

- Is there a complete list of the incompatibilites that `nath` has and how to solve them?
- Is there any chance that I can use `nath` without having to code loads of workarounds or drop other useful packages?
- Are there `nath` alternatives that are up to date and compatible with modern packages?

Comment: I have an answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32148/250119 that allows you to toggle `nath` on and off, and it seems to work together with `amsmath`/other packages. (not very throughoutly tested)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just to remove this from the unanswered questions:

> Is there a complete list of the incompatibilites that nath has and how to solve them?

No, the list would be quite large, probably.

> Is there any chance that I can use nath without having to code loads of workarounds or drop other useful packages?

No, the `nath` package does many sorts of evil tricks that creating some sandbox around it is impossible.

> Are there `nath` alternatives that are up to date and compatible with modern packages?

I'd say no. There is `breqn` that tries doing automatic splitting of long equations, but it also has incompatibilities and seems to be unmaintained, at the moment.