# What does "Limit controls must follow a math operator" mean?

Tags: errors, amsmath, nath

When I try to compile this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \argmin \log(\sum_{x=1}^2 x^2)
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I get:

```
Test.tex:7: Limit controls must follow a math operator
Test.tex:7: Limit controls must follow a math operator
```

What exactly does this mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Drop the [`nath` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/nath). Or rather, why are you using it?

Comment: @Werner: Oh, I'm trying to use it to auto-size parentheses. Is there a problem with using `nath`?

Comment: You're already auto-sizing parentheses using `\left`...`\right`. Auto-sizing is not always the best... use the `\big`-family rather (also supplied by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)).

Comment: @Werner: Sorry I didn't mean to include the `\left` and `\right`, that was left over from my testing... will remove.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order for the automatic resizing of delimiters to work, `nath` redefines a lot of TeX internals. `amsmath` also defines a lot of TeX internals. Neither `nath` nor `amsmath` take into consideration that some other package might redefine the internal macros, and hence the error.

By default, `\log` is defined as follows:

```
> \log=macro:
->\mathop {\operator@font log}\nolimits .
l.3 \show\log
```

But, after loading `amsopn` (which is loaded by `amsmath`), we get

```
> \log=macro:
->\qopname \relax o{log}.
l.5 \show\log
```

This is the reason that the following minimal document fails:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nath}
\usepackage{amsopn}

\begin{document}
$\log$
\end{document}
```

So, you must choose between loading `amsmath` and `nath`. For example, your minimal example can be processes without loading `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nath}
\makeatletter
\def\argmin{\mathop{\operator@font arg\,min}\nolimits}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \argmin \log( \sum_{i=1}^2 x^2)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Another option is to save and restore the meaning of operators like `\log`, `\max`,`\arg`, `\sin`, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\normallog \log
\usepackage{amsmath,nath}
\let\log \normallog
\makeatletter
\def\argmin{\mathop{\operator@font arg\,min}\nolimits}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \argmin \log( \sum_{i=1}^2 x^2)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

`nath` provides some macros for display math (`\wall .. \return`); some of the other packages that are part of `amsmath` bundle (`amsgen`, `amstext`, `amsfonts`) work with `nath`.

**EDIT**: It seems that `nath` is at fault here. `nath` redefines `\mathop`. Quoting from `nath.sty`:

> \mathop is redefined to stop misinterpretation of following Bins  as unary operators (cf. TeXbook, p. 170).
>
> The following definition determines spacing between Op and Bin.
>    (According to [TeXBook, p. 170], ``such case never arises, 
>    so plain TeX leaves it undefined, making the Bin into unary.'')

If you simply restore the definition of `\mathop`, then everything works fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nath}
\makeatletter
\let\mathop\o@mathop
\makeatother
\DeclareMathOperator{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \argmin \log(\sum_{x=1}^2 x^2)
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm, so it's impossible to use `log` correctly if we include both `amsmath` and `nath`?

Comment: You could always save and restore the meaning of macros: `\let\normallog\log \usepackage{amsmath} \let\log\normallog`, etc.

Comment: Right, but the definition becomes corrupted as-is, right? +1

Comment: @Mehrdad: See edited solution.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Do keep in mind that `nath` does not play well with many package: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/104532/323. Sometimes the workarounds are easy, sometimes not.